# Send certain events to a website in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to simulate a click on a element on a website. The website contains a list and every element is expandable. The element i want to click on causes an entry of the list to expand, so its something like a "show detailed info" button.

First, here is the html code where the button is defined:

```
<td>
   <span id="span_details62_0">
     <a href="#" onclick="setBusy(&#x27;running-indication&#x27;);
            render_event_cluster(&#x27;104,105&#x27;, 620);
            toggle_fe(&#x27;dtlsRow620&#x27;);
            change(&#x27;span_details62_0&#x27;, &#x27;show&#x27;);
            Element.update(&#x27;running-indication&#x27;,&#x27;&#x27;);; return false;"><img alt="show | hide" border="0" height="10" src="/images/layout/general/clear.gif?1408570117" title="Show/hide details" width="10" /></a>
   </span>
</td>
```

Is it possible to send the commands

```
        render_event_cluster(&#x27;104,105&#x27;, 620);
        toggle_fe(&#x27;dtlsRow620&#x27;);
        change(&#x27;span_details62_0&#x27;, &#x27;show&#x27;);
```

directly to the website, thus making it think that the button has been click and the result are showed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can with `page.evaluate()`. You will need to "decode" (`&#x27;` is an HTML entity for `'`) the JavaScript first:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    setBusy('running-indication');
    render_event_cluster('104,105', 620);
    toggle_fe('dtlsRow620');
    change('span_details62_0', 'show');
    Element.update('running-indication','');
});
```

Comment: I tried that and in the screenshot afterwards the icon of the button looks like it has been clicked but the list is NOT expanded, so i can't see more than before. Also the "620" from render_event_cluster('104,105', 620); changes everytime, does that matter?

Comment: It probably does matter. You should debug it yourself. Also, you can see if there are errors when you do this: please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)).

Comment: How do I register the things you mentioned? Sorry I'm not very familiar with JavaScript / phantomjs

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see the link. I included you code in my script but there is no additional output. Is that normal?

Comment: It means that there is no error, so you're on your own.

Comment: Ah wait a sec. I think i made a mistake. First, here is my entire script: http://pastebin.com/dKwu2Zg5 and here is the new console output with your code: http://pastebin.com/TA31q901

Comment: Oh and i noticed that the "620" does not change everytime. It only changed because there is a new entry in the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88465/discussion-between-helyx-and-artjom-b).

Answer (score 0):

the [click method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) should work for you:

```
var a = document.getElementById('span_details62_0').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
a.click();
```

Comment: That does not work. a.click is not defined. If i try this: 
      var a = document.getElementById("span_details62_2");  
      var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      a.dispatchEvent(e);
      a.waitforload = true;
   e.waitforload = true;

it executes the code, but nothing happens